# Почему JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj) не копирует методы из объекта obj?

Tags: javascript, json

```
const obj = {
 field: 'some txt',
 someFn: function() {
   return 'hey'
 }
}

let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

/* result
{
 field:"some txt"
}
*/
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: ```JSON.stringify(objWithFunction,(key, val) => {
  if (typeof val === 'function') {
    return val + '';
  }
  return val;
});```

Comment: JSON формат для обмена _данными_ для различных платформ. было бы несколько странным ожидать, что вдруг он для js будет каким-то образом копировать функции.

Comment: Если добавить такую строчку, то результат изменится: `obj.someFn.toJSON = obj.someFn.toString;`

Answer (score 3):

Потому что [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) не поддерживает такие значения, как [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) или [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) (далее цитата из документации):

> Значение undefined, функция или символ, встреченные во время преобразования, будут либо опущены (если они найдены в объекте), либо превращены в null (если они найдены в массиве).

Если вам необходимо принудительно копировать методы, то вы можете определить свой `replacer`, в котором будете проверять, является ли элемент копирования функцией и приводить её к строке, а затем в [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) определить функцию `reviver`, в которой будете преобразовывать строку с телом функции в саму функцию, например [конструктором Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: Ещё NaN и пара бесконечностей. Впрочем, они всегда меняются на null - даже в полях.

Comment: А вот BigInt'ы по стандарту должны давать TypeError.